# Dynamic Sql Convert inserting varbinary data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been stuck on a dynamic sql issue.
I need to be able to save varbinary (byte[]) data into my table.

Here is sample code just to show my problem:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ins_photo
@schema VARCHAR(63), @name VARCHAR(50), @data VARBINARY(MAX)
AS

PRINT @data;

EXEC ('

PRINT '''+@data+''';

DECLARE @plswork VARBINARY(MAX) = CAST('''+@data+''' AS VARBINARY(MAX))

PRINT @plswork;

INSERT INTO '+@schema+'.Tester
(name, photo)
VALUES
(
'''+@name+''',
@plswork
)
')
```

And here is the output:

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010000
?????A
0x3F3F3F3F3F410100

(1 row(s) affected)
```

As you will notice in the conversion the initial binary data and the "converted" are different, therefor when retrieving the binary data to display an image ... well reveals nothing :)

I would really appreciate help or even a work around, but the main thing is that this usp will need to call different tables dependent on schema. (Hence why i am using dynamic sql)

Could i save the images as nvarchar(max) and on the client side use ToBase64String() ?, i wouldve thought this is a bad solution but not too sure

Thanking in advance
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you facing this issue. But instead of concatenating the @data to dynamic sql string, try passing it as a parameter. Refer the example mentioned below.

```
DECLARE @Color varchar(16) = 'Blue', @LastProduct varchar(64)
SET @SQL =       N'SELECT @pLastProduct = max(Name)
                   FROM AdventureWorks2008.Production.Product
                   WHERE Color = @pColor'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@pColor varchar(16),
                        @pLastProduct varchar(64) OUTPUT'
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL
            @SQL,
            @ParmDefinition,
            @pColor = @Color,
            @pLastProduct OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a VARCHAR variable instead VARBINARY into EXEC query string.

Add

```
DECLARE @dataCHAR VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @dataCHAR = @data;
```

So procedure will look like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ins_photo
@schema VARCHAR(63), @name VARCHAR(50), @data VARBINARY(MAX)
AS

PRINT @data;

DECLARE @dataCHAR VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @dataCHAR = @data;

EXEC ('

PRINT '''+@dataCHAR+''';

DECLARE @plswork VARBINARY(MAX) = CAST('''+@dataCHAR+''' AS VARBINARY(MAX))

PRINT @plswork;

INSERT INTO '+@schema+'.Tester
(name, photo)
VALUES
(
'''+@name+''',
@plswork
)
')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it does work with a small (very small) image, larger images it fails... hmmmm

Comment: For the problem i presented your solution was correct, so thank you very much, on implementation though i use large images, so the other answer is "more" correct.. thank you again though much appreciated